# Reset Windows 10 completely

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, crash, reset

Before I had Windows 10, my PC crashed very rarely. Then I installed Windows 10 Insider Preview. Now it is **crashing at least two times a week**. One reason is that about 1000 processes of "Java Web Launcher" are started at the same moment so RAM and CPU are overloaded.

Apart from that, I get a **bluescreen** very often. Here are the error messages I wrote down:

- FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE
- MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
- CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED
- KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
- PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
- BAD_POOL_HEADER
- IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
- SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

(I can't see any pattern here!)

Another annoying thing is that the Windows bar doesn't work properly: I can't open the Windows menu, Windows search/ Cortana and the notifications. And I can't right-click a program icon on the Windows bar.

---

I wanted to downgrade to Windows 7, but the deadline of 30 days was expired, so I resetted Windows 10. I made a backup for all my important files, connected an empty, bootable USB stick and downloaded a program which should re-install Windows 10.

Oddly enough, it ran directly from the downloads folder without using the USB stick. The installation did work. But after it, the old files were not deleted, they were just moved to the folder "Windows.old", and some programs, like XAMPP were not removed completely. And after one week, **the old bugs occurred again**, even more frequently.

With all the crashes and bugs, my PC is nearly useless. What should I do to **reset my PC properly**? If necessary, I would switch to Linux, but I prefer Windows.

Comment: It is great that you give so much detail, but sometimes is can be confusing when you talk about too much. Your title says "Reset Windows 10 Completely", then talk about Windows 7. So, what do you want to do? Go back to 7 or clean install 10? Please clarify.

Comment: Uninstall Java?

Comment: "downloaded a program which should re-install Windows 10." - What did you download specifically?  If you performed a Reset, you already have, reset Windows 10 completely.

Comment: The program is the MediaCreationTool by Microsoft.

Comment: @Aloso  - So you created a bootable installation disk, performed a wipe of your HDD, and programs were still there?  You are leaving vital information out.  Feel free to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well part of the problem is that you're using `Windows Insider Preview` aka **not a stable version**. It specifically says:

> Download and install the preview only if you
>
> - Want to try out software that’s still in development and like sharing your opinion about it.
> - Don’t mind lots of updates or a UI design that might change significantly over time.
> - Really know your way around a PC and feel comfortable troubleshooting problems, backing up data, formatting a hard drive, installing an operating system from scratch, or restoring your old one if necessary.
> - Know what an ISO file is and how to use it.
> - **Aren't installing it on your everyday computer.**

As far as reverting back to Windows 7, you'll have to save your data on some sort of external device, and then reformat your disk again for Windows 7. With the insider preview, you may be able to do a Windows 10 upgrade, which should stop all of your issues. However, that's your choice if you want to install a Windows 10 *Stable Version* or go back to Windows 7.

Comment: I didn't disable windows update. The full version was automatically installed.

Comment: @Ramhound "I installed Windows 10 Insider Preview" Insider builds are public level beta builds.

Comment: I installed the Insider Preview because I tried it out before Windows 10 was officially available. Switching to a stable version afterwards didn't help.

Comment: @Aloso when you switched, did you do a full clean install or what?

Comment: @DrZoo - I must have missed that statement.

Comment: @Aloso - So what version are you running now?  You can determine that by doing `winver` in a run prompt.  You can avoid all those extra processes from starting by using Safe Mode.

Comment: @Aloso if you're in a stable build, check your drivers. You probably have some that are out of date. If you know how to use WinDBG you can also get more information about the BSODs, or post the .dmp files to a link where we can download them.